# How to translate exceptions from Tasks returned by asynchronous ASP.NET Web API methods?

Tags: .net, exception, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

When Tasks returned by (asynchronous) ASP.NET Web API controller methods throw exceptions, I would like to translate known exceptions to `HttpResponseException`. Is there some way to intercept these exceptions, and throw `HttpResponseException` instead?

The following code snippet should demonstrate the type of asynchronous API controller method I'm talking about.

```
class ObjectApiController : ApiController
{
    public Task<Object> GetObjectByIdAsync(string id)
    [...]
}
```

Let me know if I need to provide more information about what I'm trying to do.

**EDIT:**
Specifically I'd like to know if there's some kind of hook with which I can intercept exceptions from Tasks returned by ApiController methods, and translate said exceptions to HttpResponseException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use an ExceptionFilter to do this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Formats uncaught exception in a common way, including preserving requested Content-Type
/// </summary>
public class FormatExceptionsFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        Exception exception = actionExecutedContext.Exception;

        if (exception != null)
        {            
            HttpRequestMessage request = actionExecutedContext.Request;

            // we shouldn't be getting unhandled exceptions
            string msg = "Uncaught exception while processing request {0}: {1}";
            AspLog.Error(msg.Fmt(request.GetCorrelationId().ToString("N"), exception), this); 

            // common errror format, without sending stack dump to the client
            HttpError error = new HttpError(exception.Message);
            HttpResponseMessage newResponse = request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                error);
            actionExecutedContext.Response = newResponse; 

        }
    }

}
```

It is registered like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new ApiControllers.FormatExceptionsFilterAttribute());

        // other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code is only one of the ways:

```
class ObjectApiController : ApiController
{
    public Task<Object> GetObjectByIdAsync(string id)
    {

        return GetObjAsync().ContinueWith(task => { 

            if(task.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted) { 
                var tcs = TaskCompletionSource<object>();

                // set the status code to whatever u need.
                tcs.SetException(new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));

                return tcs.Task;
            }

            // TODO: also check for the cancellation if applicable

            return task;
        });
    }
}
```

If you are on .NET 4.5 and want to use async/await, your job will be easier.

**Edit**

According to your comments, I guess you want something generic. If that's the case, use exception filters as @tcarvin suggested.

Comment: I am on .NET 4.5 and am trying to use await, but due to what looks more and more like a .NET bug, my top-level exception handler (catch block) doesn't get invoked. Trying to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I was more thinking along the lines of some hook to intercept all unobserved Task exceptions emanating from ApiController methods though? This would be much preferable to handling Task exceptions in each method. This is perhaps not possible?

Comment: After rewriting my API controller method, I somehow got exception handling in conjunction with await working. Yet I have no idea how I fixed it :/

Comment: @aknuds1 why don't u use Exception filters then?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Exception filters, will they work with exceptions from Tasks?

Comment: @aknuds1 sure, underlying framework knows how to handle async actions.